# Identifying parameters in BUGS linear regression

Tags: regression, bugs, identifiability

With a linear regression defined in BUGS, how should one implement model identification constraints such as having the mean of a group of parameters be zero, or having the group of parameters sum to zero?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm thinking of a model with, say, varying slopes, e.g.,

```
for (i in 1:N) {
  y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
  mu[i] <- beta0 + beta1[group[i]]*x1[i]
}
```

What's the right way to specify that the mean of all the beta1[] is zero? I *don't* want to say that each beta1[group[i]] is drawn from a distribution with zero mean; I do want to say that all the beta1[] are drawn from a distribution the mean of which is fixed at zero. In pseudocode that is probably not legal BUGS or even JAGS, something like

```
for (j in 1:nGroups) {
  beta1[j] ~ dnorm(0, beta1.tau)
}
mean(beta1.mu) <- 0
```

Comment: You're going to have a problem with that particular formulation; by setting `beta1[i] <- y[i] / x1[i]` and `beta0 <- 0`, the errors will all be zero.  You've got $N+1$ parameters and only $N$ observations...

Comment: Of course, you're right. The slopes should be at the group level, not at the individual level; fixed.

Comment: What is the distinction between "beta1[group[i]] is drawn from a distribution with zero mean" and "all the beta1[] are drawn from a distribution the mean of which is fixed at zero"?  If all the beta1[] are drawn from a distribution the mean of which is fixed at zero, then necessarily each beta1[group[i]] is drawn from a distribution the mean of which is fixed at zero...  but the posterior mean for each beta1[group[i]] won't be zero unless a miracle occurs, if that's your concern.

Comment: In the former case, I'm expressing my prior belief that the beta1[] are drawn from a distribution with zero mean. In the latter case, I want to constrain the posterior means of each beta1[j] such that if I take the mean of these posterior means, I'll get zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:  Answer substantially rewritten in light of clarifying comments.  You can do it in several ways; probably the simplest is to force $\sum_{j=1}^{NGroups} \beta_j = 0$ at every iteration of the sampler.  This will ensure that the mean across all samples will also equal zero.

```
for (i in 1:N) {
   y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
   mu[i] <- beta0 + beta[group[i]]*x1[i] 
}

for (j in 1:(NGroups-1)) {  
   beta[j] ~ dnorm(0, tau.beta)
}
beta[NGroups] <- - sum(beta[1:(NGroups-1)])
```

Comment: That's very helpful, and thank you for putting up with the unclear early versions of the question. If there are other ways of forcing the constraint that illustrate somehow meaningful differences, please post them. Also, under $\Sigma^{NGroups}_{j=1}\beta_j=0$, is $\beta_j$ still interpretable just as the other $\beta$ parameters?

Comment: Sorry about the delay responding - yes, $\beta_{NGroups}$ is still just as interpretable, and in the same manner, as the other $\beta_j$.  They are all subject to the caveat that the zero-sum constraint was imposed on them, but they are all still "real" $\beta$s.